# Is it possible to find open questions with just one answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

On Biblical Hermeneutics, we are trying to provide [second opinions](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/68).  It seems we can search for open questions with no answers:

```
answers:0 is:question closed:no
```

Or open questions with one or more answers:

```
answers:1 is:question closed:no
```

But we can't easily find the questions with exactly one (1) answer.  Or at least, I haven't discovered a way to do that.

Comment: There is no way to do so.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Hmm... Sounds like I should turn this into a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: That's a cool idea. (Providing a second opinion, I mean)

Comment: @Pekka: I was hoping there was a `not` operator: `answers:1 !answers:2`.  Nope! (Or rather, "not". ;-)  Also, it seems `answers:X` turns on `is:question`, so we can shorten the URL a bit that way.

Comment: I think the only way to conjure up such a query would be through the data explorer.

Comment: @JeffMercado: The data explorer doesn't cover beta sites. :(

Comment: @Caleb: Which is the unfortunate part.

Comment: +1, this would be an amazing thing to be able to do.  Could probably be userscript'd though...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I was reviewing the [revisions to the search announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/160100/revisions) when something stuck out in rev 14:

> - New range support, here are some examples:
>
>   - `answers:1..1` (exactly one answer)
>   - `answers:10..20` (10 to 20 answers)

It totally works.  [Here are all open PHP questions with exactly one answer, which has not been accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1..1+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano).  You can also use the range operator for score, and probably all of the other things that are numbers.  For example, [here are all 24,000 PHP questions with negative scores](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A-100..-1), down to -100.

All Hail Elasticsearch!

Comment: There are only 24,000?

Comment: The `cv-ring` also issues `delv-pls` requests and are very aggressive about it.  Questions with negative score are also routinely automatically pruned by the system.  [Here's the current low-score winner in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12148621/168868), at -14.

Comment: As it turns out, I'd [noticed that too](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/430/revisions "An hour or two before you posted.").  It looks like the notation has already been updated, but I'm sure when it's stable this will be the right answer and I'll get (my second) [meta-tag:status-complete] [meta-tag:feature-request].