# How to refer to a Stack Q&A item?

Tags: discussion

When answering a Question and linking to a related Q&A, or simply an A, I'm never quite sure of what to use:

1. Check this *Q&A*
2. Check this *Post*
3. Check this *Thread*

Probably, this is just a matter of semantics and personal preference, but was wondering if there is any definition, or standard terminology, or a blog post about this. Searching this Meta hasn't brought any insight.

Normally I use `1`.
And maybe `2` and `3` are for blogs and forums, respectively.

Comment: Check this answer or question is what I use; usually with a titled link so it is clear what is being linked to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, nice recall, most of the times I use a titled link too.

Comment: When I'm doing support and want the user to look at *both* the question and the answer, I say "post" as a catchall.

Comment: @Aarthi: The trouble is, at least for a [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet#Introduction "comp.lang.perl.misc for the win!") old-timer like myself, "post" tends to mean the work of an individual and "thread" tends to mean a group of posts using the same subject.

Comment: @JonEricson That's legit -- I also will say "page" if I'm feeling a bit more general. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 and 2 are fine, I usually use "Q&A" if I want them to read both the question and answer(s), "post" if I only link to and care about one answer. Number 3, "thread," is explicitly not what  we want. We are not a forum, we don't want threads, just questions and answers. That is why there are a number of suggestions to this effect: the FAQ, the rep requirement to post comments, post flags such as "Not an answer," comment flags (especially "too chatty"), the automatic suggestion to migrate comments to chat, etc.

Answer (score -5):

Might I suggest we coin a new term:

- quan?

It is the [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "QUestion&ANswer(s)".  The word covers questions with [any number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161838/1438) of answers including 0.  The plural form ("quans") designates multiple questions and not a single question with multiple answers.

It already has (a potentially confusing) [meaning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quan) in a few languages, but not (yet) in English.

Comment: Wow, Lewis Carroll and a loop! *The word "portmanteau" itself is thus a portmanteau.* Nice readings, thanks!

Comment: Surely this should be quandan (QUestionsANDANswers) or quanan or something..?